# There are four men and each one has its own chair. In how many ways can the men sit without sitting on their own chairs?

Tags: combinatorics

They can't sit on their chairs. In how many ways can I distribute them?

Mark $\rightarrow$ Chair M

Paul $\rightarrow$ Chair P

Steve $\rightarrow$ Chair S

Joe $\rightarrow$ Chair J

Another question:

I've seen a guy solving this problem with the following formula:

$\frac {n!}{e}$ ; where n is the number of men and their own chairs.

Using this formula you get approximately $8.8$. Then the guy said the answer is the nearest whole number, $9$.  I wish if someone could say if it works and why.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as *derangement*. Check the general case, it is quite illuminating.

One way is to use the inclusion-exclusion principle: The total number of seating arrangements is $4! = 24$ (first one selects among 4, second among 3, ...). We need to substract the ones where at least one of the gentlemen gets his own chair. Say $A$ gets his own chair, there are $3$ others that can get seated in $3!$ ways, but $A$ could be any one. This is $\binom{4}{1} \cdot 3!$ ways. Similarly, at least $2$ getting their own chairs is $\binom{4}{2} \cdot 2!$, $3$ gives $\binom{4}{3} \cdot 1!$ and $4$ is $\binom{4}{4} \cdot 0!$. We need to weed out double counting (inclusion-exclusion):
$$
\binom{4}{0} \cdot 4! 
  - \binom{4}{1} \cdot 3!
  + \binom{4}{2} \cdot 2!
  - \binom{4}{1} \cdot 3!
  + \binom{4}{0} \cdot 0!
  = 4! \left(
         \frac{1}{0!} - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!}
       \right)
  = 9
$$